# Compress botframework file upload image in BotFramework WebChat?

Tags: reactjs, botframework

Can compress Images uploaded in botframework below 4mb before sending on web.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "compress". I assume you mean "file compression", as in zipping the file. If you are wanting to send the image as a file and not display it, then yes. If you are looking to display the image, then no. The limit of 4MB applies to uncompressed images.